# Creating a lottery game of some sort

Tags: java

i am creating a lottery type game where players are able to click a button, and they can then get a random amount of coins (a high amount being rare and low amount being common.)

So far all i could think of is an array, is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
private static final int[] REWARDS = {10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000};
```

Comment: That seems fine to me, if you wish to specify the exact rewards then an array is fine.

Comment: Is [`Collections#shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) what you are looking for?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: `shuffle()` is good for uniform distribution without repeats. This is clearly not the case here

Comment: Why do you think that your current approach may not be efficient? What is your actual issue?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a weighted probability model.  E.g.

```
Prize : Weight
---------------    
$10 : 50
$25 : 20
$50 : 10
$100 : 5
$250 : 3
$500 : 2
$1000 : 1
```

The total weight here can be counted as 91.  So to award a prize, you pick a random number from 1-91.  Then find where it sits in your weighted range (e.g. by subtracting each tier's weight from your number until it goes negative).

BUT be careful here for off-by-one errors and test thoroughly.